# Flask-login not importing

Tags: python, flask, backend, flask-login

I'm trying to import Flask-login so I can use it:

```
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_required
```

However, it doesn't seem to import correctly, returning this error:

```
TypeError: login_required() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

I have user loaders, etc.:

```py
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.session_protection = 'strong'
login_manager.login_view = 'account.login'

login_manager.init_app(app)


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return app.get(user_id)


@login_manager.unauthorized_handler
def unauthorized():
    return "Unauthorized!"
```

When running `pip3 install flask-login`, it shows that it's already there. It's important to note there is no error when *running* it, however my IDE shows there is no module named `flask-login`.

Comment: first of a `TypeError` wouldn't be raised if that was an import issue, if it couldn't import it then it would most likely raise `ImportError`, second, I don't see anywhere in your provided code that you would have used `login_required()`

Comment: To add from @Matiiss' comment, `login_required()` is designed to be used as a decorator. So somewhere you will have @login_required over a function.